# What are a few backpacking foods that have the calories yet are lightweight?

Tags: hiking, camping, backpacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most efficient food to take a for a 12-15 day hiking trip?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-is-the-most-efficient-food-to-take-a-for-a-12-15-day-hiking-trip)
>   [A list of suitable foods for a long hike](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/a-list-of-suitable-foods-for-a-long-hike)

I normally carry brown rice, oatmeal, instant potatoes, and powdered soups with other seasonings that make the flavor a little better. Does anyone have any suggestions for other backpacking foods that have the calories yet are lightweight?

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-is-the-most-efficient-food-to-take-a-for-a-12-15-day-hiking-trip) and [this one](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/a-list-of-suitable-foods-for-a-long-hike?lq=1), and they both have many good answers.

Comment: @Eyal - yes, I think it is pretty much a dupe of your second one.

Answer (score 1):

1. buckwheat (very fast to cook, 10-15 min. or so)
2. nuts
3. raisin